# Miniprofiler gem generating a lot of 404 errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack-mini-profiler

The [Miniprofiler](http://miniprofiler.com/) gem for rails is very handy. ([github](https://github.com/SamSaffron/MiniProfiler/tree/master/Ruby), [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/368-miniprofiler))

However, I am getting a lot of 404 errors in my application:

In the chrome console, tab network:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) http://localhost.mysite.com/mini-profiler-resources/results

This page returns the following response: `Request not found:  - user 127.0.0.1`

On every page, I have 9 of those requests. (so it clogs my logs, and it's annoying). And 9 more show up every time I trigger an ajax request.

It seems that mini profiler is trying to evaluate the time of a request that doesn't happen... How can I troubleshoot this situation ?

---

*Update:* I've noticed that this gem also make the loading of images very slow. The images have a pending time (in the network tab) that ranges from 1 to 20 seconds, then they are loaded. Visually, you see images popping one after another very slowly.

I've tried to fiddle with the development.rb config settings (`config.consider_all_requests_local`, `config.assets.debug`, `config.cache_classes`, and `config.assets.compress`) without success. I have also tried to change my domain (dev.mysite.com with entry in `/etc/hosts`, localhost, 127.0.0.1 and localhost:3000). In every case, the gem makes image loading very slow. If I remove the gem, it's fast again.

*Update 2*: Sometimes (and I still don't know why), images load fast even with the gem after restarting the server. So the situation is like this:

- Miniprofiler included in gemfile => 404 errors, images load slowly 90% of the time
- Miniprofile not included in gemfile => No 404 errors, images load normally

Answer (score 3):

`rm -fr tmp/miniprofiler` worked for me. found it here https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler/issues/71

Answer (score 1):

I looks like it was a problem with rights:

I was starting the server with `rvmsudo rails server -p 80`, and that caused miniprofiler to put files in tmp/miniprofiler as root.

Before (with `rvmsudo rails server -p 80`):

```
$> ls -la tmp/miniprofiler/mp_timers
-rw-r--r--  1 root  root  1427 Aug 31 17:18 tmp/miniprofiler/mp_timers_14p99y...
...
```

=> 404 errors and slow images

After: (with `rails s`)

```
$> ls -la tmp/miniprofiler/mp_timers
-rw-r--r--  1 pinouchon  staff  1427 Aug 31 17:18 tmp/miniprofiler/mp_timers_14p99y...
...
```

=> no 404 errors and images load normally.

---

The only problem with that is that I can't start my server on port 80: it says

```
$> rails s -p 80
Exiting
/Users/sharewizz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@sharewizz/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:526:in `start_tcp_server': no acceptor (port is in use or requires root privileges) (RuntimeError)
    from /Users/sharewizz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@sharewizz/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:526:in `start_server`
```

Because only root can start application on port less than 1024...

Comment: Thanks for posting this. Came across the same error except I don't know why my files had an issue as I didn't start the server as root. Anyway, I just did a "sudo rm -r tmp/miniprofiler/*" seemed to sort it out.